# Non-greedy regex match when searching from end

Tags: objective-c, regex, nsregularexpression

I read that you should use `?` to match text non-greedily, so the regex

```
http://.*?\.png
```

...used on

```
http://example.png.png
```

...would return `http://example.png`.

But the non-greediness only seems to work from left to right.  That is, if I matched it on

```
http://http://example.png
```

...it would return `http://http://example.png`.

How can I get the code to match `http://example.png` only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
http://[A-Za-z0-9_-]+\.png
```

It wont get the first `http://` because it has more than `[A-Za-z0-9_-]+` between it and `.png`

Could also use this if you are worried about other characters in the URL:

```
http://[^:]+?\.png
```

Comment: Thanks!  Do all URLs only consist of A-Z, a-z, 0-9, -, _, and %?

Comment: I've never even seen a URL with `%` to be honest. You could replace the `[A-Za-z0-9_-]` portion with `[^:]+?` and it would probably work fine for any of your cases if you are worried about that.

Comment: Oh I just realized on issue with URLs with port numbers. like http://google.com:80/ which is a valid url, but I don't think is matched by this regex.

Comment: True enough, I suppose the negative look ahead would work better if this is a concern. I'm sort of curious what the use case of this is.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a negative look ahead too, but I think smerny 's answer is better.

```
http://(?!http://).*?\.png
```